# Prevent simultaneous concurrent & maximum logins in User group

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, authentication

is it possible to allow only one concurrent login per user in Asp.Net web application?

I am working on one web application in which i want to make sure that website allow only one login per user at a time . How to check that current user already logged in or not .

Also I wanted to Limit no of logins per group as defined. like Maximum 10 IT department people can login at a time, maximum 5 HR department people can login.

I am using simple database to store the login information

Comment: It is your system and you should already know if user is logged in or not... (may need to implement some sort of heartbeat to keep "I'm still logged in" functionality). Side note: such design may lead to painful user experience; consider removing comment on storing "information like ... *password*" in DB as it is very bad idea.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov actually I want to detect if login attempt is tried through different sessions or different ips

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The problem isn't actually quite that easy.  Determining that an account is being accessed simultaneously from two different machines, while also not kicking out users who are accessing the site from a single machine, is a bit more involved than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are two different things that you need to keep track of here and check on.

The first is that, when someone logs in, you'll want to invalidate any previous sessions for that username.  This prevents the trivial case of someone logging in on one machine and then logging in on another machine, as the first machine will no longer be able to make any new authenticated requests.  This will be sufficient in most cases for dealing with users who aren't actively trying to subvert this restriction.

The next is a little bit more complicated.  What you need to look for is users making requests to your sever using the same authenticated session ID but with different IPs, broswers, etc.  What you'll be looking for is dealing with the case where one person logs in, then looks at the session information in their cookie, and then re-creates an identical cookie with the same session ID on another machine.

That second approach does have its issues though.  Most people don't have entirely static IPs.  An *entirely* static IP is actually very rare.  That said, for most users their IP is not rotated very often; they're unlikely to see it change while actively using the site.  These people are not going to have any problems if using the site appropriate.  However, there are going to be some people who's internet providers will rotate their IPs frequently.  These people may not be doing anything inappropriate either.  If you don't deal with the fact that people's IPs may be frequently changing you could end up constantly kicking out all users from certain internet providers.  What you really want to be looking out for is cases where there is an action performed by a user with a given IP/session, then an action on the same account from a different IP with the same session, then more actions from the first IP, followed by more from the second, etc.  When you see this flip flopping between two IPs in a very short span of time, it's a strong indication that two people on two different machines are accessing the account.  You can further improve this metric by incorporating other aspects of each request, such as the browser information (with the version, down to the lowest version component).

Comment: am also wanted to limit the maximum no of users login per group, is there any suggestion?

Comment: @RohitChaudhari You'd use the exact same techniques, you'd just only start invalidating sessions when the count is greater than a number other than one.

Comment: +1: Since OP is probably building some sort of game it is useful information. For regular applications such efforts are probably overkill - it may be easier to simply allow many logins and deal with conflicts server side.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Well *all* of this is done server side, not client side.  Client side validations would be trivially subvertable.  That said, yes, most applications don't need this.  Games are one glaring exception, although I could imagine other applications potentially considering this.  For example, any site requiring a paid subscription may want to prevent one person buying a subscription and then sharing it with a bunch of their friends, so that they don't all need to buy one.